# error in using the genfromtxt() function in python/numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am relatively new to python and I was trying to use the genfromtext() function.
I am reading data from a csv file converting it to an array in numpy and reading specific columns  from the array that I want to use.  The array has a row of headings which I do not need. One of the columns in the array is a string of characters and the rest are integers.  I would like to isloate the string and the one column of integers.  Here is what I have tried so far.

```
import csv 
import os 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

csv_to_array2 = np.genfromtxt('test.csv',    
delimiter = ',' , dtype = "S5, S5, S5, S5, S5, S5" ) 

numrows2 = len(csv_to_array2)
numcols2 = len((csv_to_array2).T)
print(numrows2)
print(numcols2) 


head_and_data2 = np.vsplit(csv_to_array2, np.array([1]) ) 

data2 = head_and_data2[1]
data_split2 = np.hsplit(data2, np.array([1,2]))
print(data2)

col_title= data_split2[0]
y = data_split2[1]
print(col_title)
```

my test file is the following

```
  ,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5
  p1,1,2,3,4,5
  p2,6,7,8,9,10
  p3,11,12,13,14,15
  p4,16,18,18,19,20
  p5,21,22,23,24,25
```

When I run the program the output is the following

```
[(b'', b'n1', b'n2', b'n3', b'n4', b'n5')
 (b'p1', b'1', b'2', b'3', b'4', b'5')
 (b'p2', b'6', b'7', b'8', b'9', b'10')
 (b'p3', b'11', b'12', b'13', b'14', b'15')
 (b'p4', b'16', b'18', b'18', b'19', b'20')
 (b'p5', b'21', b'22', b'23', b'24', b'25')]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/shubha/workspace/Raj_Data/Test_part.py", line 24, in <module>
    head_and_data2 = np.vsplit(csv_to_array2, np.array([1]) ) 
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py", line 590, in vsplit
    raise ValueError('vsplit only works on arrays of 2 or more dimensions')
ValueError: vsplit only works on arrays of 2 or more dimensions
```

When I change the `dtype= None`  I get the correct columns, but with the 'b' appended before each entry.  So for the second column first row(after the heading has been removed) I get b'1' etc.  When I remove the dtype, it gives me an error that it cannot read the first column, each entry is a 'nan'

I would appreciate any help that you can give me. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working `genfromtxt`.  You must be running Python3, and that's why you are seeing the byte strings.  Don't worry about them.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do when puzzled by the output of `genfromtxt` is to print the array's `shape` and `dtype`.

The `b'1'` is the Python3 way of displaying a byte string.  A file like this is read as bytes.

I can simulate your data file with a byte text file.  I'm working in Python3, where strings are unicode.  Byte strings are labeled with `b`.  I also added a `n0` back in.

```
In [78]: txt=b""" n0,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5
  p1,1,2,3,4,5
  p2,6,7,8,9,10
  p3,11,12,13,14,15
  p4,16,18,18,19,20
  p5,21,22,23,24,25 
"""
```

load with `genfromtxt`; `names=True` to take field names from the `1st` line; `dtype=None` to let it determine the best field type:

```
In [79]: arr=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), names=True, delimiter=',', dtype=None)
In [80]: arr
Out[80]: 
array([(b'p1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (b'p2', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
       (b'p3', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), (b'p4', 16, 18, 18, 19, 20),
       (b'p5', 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)], 
      dtype=[('n0', 'S2'), ('n1', '<i4'), ('n2', '<i4'), ('n3', '<i4'), ('n4', '<i4'), ('n5', '<i4')])
```

The result is a 5 element array, with 6 fields:

```
In [81]: arr.shape
Out[81]: (5,)
In [82]: arr.dtype
Out[82]: dtype([('n0', 'S2'), ('n1', '<i4'), ('n2', '<i4'), ('n3', '<i4'), ('n4', '<i4'), ('n5', '<i4')])
```

The `n0` field is 5 byte strings:

```
In [83]: arr['n0']
Out[83]: 
array([b'p1', b'p2', b'p3', b'p4', b'p5'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```

the `n2' field is 5 integers (same for 'n1', etc)

```
In [84]: arr['n2']
Out[84]: array([ 2,  7, 12, 18, 22])
In [85]:
```

There's no need for splits, vertical or horizontal.

I can convert the 1st field to unicode with `astype`.

```
In [86]: arr['n0'].astype('U2')
Out[86]: 
array(['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

Column (field) names can be found in the `dtype`:

```
In [87]: arr.dtype.names
Out[87]: ('n0', 'n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5')
```

I could also do the unicode conversion in the original dtype

```
In [90]: dt='U2,i,i,i,i,i'
In [91]: arr=np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), names=True, delimiter=',' ,dtype=dt)In [92]: arr
Out[92]: 
array([('p1', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ('p2', 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
       ('p3', 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), ('p4', 16, 18, 18, 19, 20),
       ('p5', 21, 22, 23, 24, 25)], 
      dtype=[('n0', '<U2'), ('n1', '<i4'), ('n2', '<i4'), ('n3', '<i4'), ('n4', '<i4'), ('n5', '<i4')])
In [93]: arr['n0']
Out[93]: 
array(['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4', 'p5'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Going by the description in the first paragraph, you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt(
    'test.csv', delimiter=',' ,
    dtype='U5, I, I, I, I, I',
    names=True, usecols=(0, 3))
print(data.dtype)
print(data)
print(data['n0'])
print(data['n3'])
```

which gives the following:

```
[('n0', '<U5'), ('n3', '<u4')]    
[('p1', 3) ('p2', 8) ('p3', 13) ('p4', 18) ('p5', 23)]    
['p1' 'p2' 'p3' 'p4' 'p5']    
[ 3  8 13 18 23]
```

This avoid the need to splitting things later (so no `vsplit` needed).

It also formats the input columns properly, by using `dtype='U5, I, I, I, I, I'` (use 'F' instead of 'I' if you want floating point), so the columns you want for calculations are integers instead of bytes.

Thanks to hpaulj for reminding me of the 'U' type use in Python 3, instead of the 'S' type (as in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514174/707650)).

Comment: Thanks.  I still get the same error as before for the vsplit function. I was trying to do this so I could use the response from the first column (the p's)

Comment: accidently hit return.

Comment: and the third column to do a principal component ananlysis , so I would like to find a way to be able to ignore the b's in the columns.  Is there a way to get that information out?  Thanks.

Comment: Why use `vsplit` when you can easily extract the two columns this way? And you shouldn't get bytes ('b' prefixes) in any column except the first: the 'I' formatters used in `genfromtxt` convert the input data directly to integers, not strings.

Comment: even if I use this method to get the column, I still get the 'b' in the array for the string.  The numerical values are okay.

Comment: Don't worry about the 'b's.

Comment: What is the best way to pick the columns and the data type if the array that you are working with is really huge? (I have an array that has 170 rows and about 50,000 columns) The data type is the same for all rows and columns except the first row and first column.

Comment: I don't understand that last question: you know what's in the table (or so I'd hope), you know what you want to do with the data, so you know what data type you want to use. Same for picking the column: you know which columns you want to use, so you select them. Again, it's all done by using the right arguments in `genfromtxt`.